# Relocate points added into a layer with different EPSG than the orthophoto layer using as reference

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

Thoundsans of points, representing singular trees in a region, were added manually into a shape layer with EPSG:23030, but it was done following visually the images from an orthophoto WMS layer with EPSG:23029.

I tried to reproject point layer from 23030 to 23029 but all points are misfit from its real position as I can see according the orthophoto WMS layer.

Is there any way to set points correctly in 23029 in QGIS?